# using dynamic memory to avoid reference invalidation

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std; //please ignore bad practices like this and everything being set to public. Its just for sake of demonstration.

vector<int>& f() {
    vector<int> a = *new vector<int>{15, 15, 16};
    return a;
}

int main () {
    vector<int>& b = f();
    
    for (auto x: b) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
delete &b;
    
    cout << "finished" << endl;
}
```

Hi:

In the code above, I'm using dynamic allocated memory so that vector a would have its memory stored on the heap, so it can avoid getting deleted after the function exits. But for some reason it didn't. The code gives me this error that can't be understood:

```
=================================================================
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000030 at pc 0x000000354a2c bp 0x7ffc1174eb30 sp 0x7ffc1174eb28
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000030 thread T0
    #1 0x7f2c73349082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x602000000030 is located 0 bytes inside of 12-byte region [0x602000000030,0x60200000003c)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #3 0x7f2c73349082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #5 0x7f2c73349082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 04 fa fa[fd]fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==22==ABORTING
```

I feel like I'm missing something --- I'll rename/reword my question more appropriately afterwards.

Edit: Corrected code looks like this

```
vector<int>& f() {
    vector<int>& a = *new vector<int>{15, 15, 16};
    return a;
}

int main () {
    vector<int>& b = f();
    
    for (auto x: b) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
delete &b;
    
    cout << "finished" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `vector<int> a = *new vector<int>{15, 15, 16};` doesn't work the way you think it would. You seem to assume that `a` "has its memory stored on the heap" because an unrelated vector at the right hand side of the initialisation has. Do you have Java or C# background by any chance?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  Java background only. The whole memory management deal is a bit new to me.

Comment: Every time you see `X a = *new X` you see two things (1) a confused Java refugee and (2) a memory leak. Java knowledge does not transfer to C++.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware that you need to delete stuff using "delete" keyword to pointer towards the original object itself on the stack. But yeah I omitted it here bc its just for the sake of example.

Comment: Can you identify the place in your code that you store a pointer to the original object so that you _could_ `delete` it later if you wanted to?

Comment: @NathanPierson I edited my code to add delete --- can you check if its done correctly? In addition, is there a way to check it myself?

Comment: Actually, your understanding of how `new` and `delete` pair together isn't quite right. Your `delete` applies to a different `vector` than the one you originally `new`'d. When you wrote `new vector<int>{15, 15, 16}`, the `vector` that was created here was _copied_ to initialize `a`, but a pointer to it was never stored anywhere in the program. Then `a` was destroyed at the end of `f()` because it had automatic storage duration, but because `b` is a dangling reference to it you try to `delete` it again. But you never tried to `delete` the original `vector`, and in fact cannot.

Comment: "I edited my code to add delete" That's not the pointer you have received from the `new` operator. That pointer is irretrievably lost at the moment `X a = *new X;` sees its semicolon.

Comment: And in any case `std::vector` is not something you normally `new`. `std::vector` is sort of a smart pointer by itself. It manages its own memory.

Comment: @NathanPierson I've updated my post to reflect the correct answer --- I think its right now.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I updated my post so that the returned vector is the dynamically allocated one, and not a deep copied one.

Comment: The last version doesn't crash, and AFAICT is *technically* correct, which as we all know is the best kind of correct (no, not really. It's the worst one. Never do this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vector<int>& f() {
    vector<int> a = *new vector<int>{15, 15, 16};
    return a;
}
```

This is calling the copy constructor of `a` and passing the heap allocated object to it. `a` is not created on the heap. It is destroyed when `f()` exits, leaving the returned reference dangling, and the heap allocated vector leaked after the constructor.

Use a reference instead of a second object. Just bind the already created vector on the heap to the reference that gets returned.

```
vector<int>& f() {
    vector<int>& a = *new vector<int>{15, 15, 16};
    return a;
}
```

While this may work, **This is bad design**

A reference is a non-owning construct, it doesn't manage the object's lifetime, while your code expects the caller to `delete` the object, this is a memory leak waiting to happen.

---

The proper way to make this code work is to simply return the vector from your function and let the compiler move it:

```
vector<int> f() {
    vector<int> a{15, 15, 16};
    return a;
}
...
vector<int> b = f();
```

Comment: In interests of completeness, you might wish to clarify (1)  The OP's code doesn't only return a dangling reference (due to destruction of `a`) - it also leaks the vector created by the `new` expression.   (2)   As you say, your first code sample works but is bad design - and that is because it forces the caller to explicitly release the `new`ed vector (via an unnecessarily clumsy syntax to obtain a pointer from the reference, and `delete`ing it) or, if the caller omits that, the result is another member leak.